# Why can't a DC magnetic field penetrate ferrous materials?

Tags: ac, dc, electromagnetism

A DC magnetic field can penetrate all types of metallic obstacles except ferrous materials. Also, the AC magnetic field faces obstruction from metallic obstacles. Why is that so?

Comment: Ferrous (iron) materials act as conductors for flux.

Comment: user2961109 If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 4):

> *A DC magnetic field can penetrate all types of metallic obstacles
> except ferrous materials.*

On the contrary, a static magnetic field can penetrate ferrous objects really quite well. Consider the case of a horseshoe magnet and an iron "keeper". When the keeper is placed across north and south poles, extraneous fields from the poles are contained within the keeper reducing the amount of external field that is detectable. If the site had images working I'd link figure 77 from [this site](https://www.rfcafe.com/references/Electricity-Basic-Navy-Training-Courses/electricity-basic-navy-training-courses-chapter-11.htm).

I will also refer you to figure 75.

> *The AC magnetic field faces obstruction from metallic obstacles. Why
> is that so?*

In an alternating magnetic field, metals that conduct will circulate eddy currents due to the process of induction. These eddy currents will create a counter-magnetic field that partially or significantly cancel the original AC field. This mechanism suggests that AC magnetic fields can be shielded by appropriate conducting objects and this can be regarded as an obstruction.

Comment: Definition of **Penetrate**: - to pierce or pass into **or through**

Comment: @BruceAbbott the op used the word so maybe this comment should be under the question. I'm perfectly happy with the definition btw.